# How to know number of rowspan in Excel Python using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

[image: cell layout]

I want to find the rowspan i.e. 4 in my case by first column containing "abc" using openpyxl in python. Its not a specific table, its somewhere in my Excel sheet and I am parsing that sheet.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to determine if a given cell is within a merged range.

The following script will return you the associated range of merged cells for a given cell. First it locates the cell where your text is, and then attempts to determine the merged cell range:

```
import openpyxl

def find_cell(ws, text):
    for row in ws.iter_rows(): 
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == text:
                return cell
    return None

def get_merged_range(ws, cell):
    if cell in ws.merged_cells:
        for merged_range in ws.merged_cell_ranges:
            if cell in [c[0] for c in openpyxl.utils.cells_from_range(merged_range)]:
                return merged_range
    return None

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'input.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

found_cell = find_cell(ws, 'abc').coordinate
print get_merged_range(ws, found_cell)
```

If the passed cell is not merged, the function will return `None`.

Comment: No need to initialise cell_range, if a cell (coordinate) hasn't been merged then the rest of the function should never execute: `return merged_range`